# Pictures in the Torah

Tags: sefer-torah

Why are there no pictures in the Torah?  It spends so much time talking about the many different events that occurred, but a picture would (possibly) provide a better (or at least other) insight into what happened.

Comment: Per your request...   https://seforimcenter.com/Super-Specials/Chumash-Meor-HaTorah---5-Volumes__p-644-8198.aspx

Comment: https://seforimcenter.com/showScannedImages.aspx?pfile=8198.gif

Comment: @YaacovDeane This is great, but I was referring to the actual Klaf itself, in a real Sefer.

Comment: It's used to be incredibly difficult to copy pictures exactly. How were you thinking these pictures would be passed on with any significant amount of precision?

Comment: @DoubleAA Good point, but if it were a basic picture I am sure good scribes would be able to copy it.

Comment: Of what value is a picture that is so simple that ancient scribes could transmit it exactly?

Comment: @DoubleAA You're right.

Comment: What goes into an actual sefer Torah is prescribed by halacha. Illustrations are not a part of it. You'll have to settle for a printed version if you want illustrations. For what it's worth, Rabbi Adin Even Yisroel Steinzaltz included illustrations in his edition of Talmud and the Koren edition, which he is also involved with has profuse illustrations. Very untraditional.

Comment: There have been detailed blueprints of the pyramids found, and those are from a similar time period to the Torah, and those were copied with enough precision to perfectly recreate pyramids. I imagine something similar could've been done with stuff like the Mishkan and the Ark, and it could've been copied with the same precision of the blueprints of the pyramids, if not better..

Comment: Well, it says "the pattern" in Exodus 25 for a bunch of stuff - that would've been GREAT to actually see them if it had been included!  Also, for the Temple stuff described as being illustrated in I Chronicles 28: 11-19, that David passed "the pattern" of to Solomon.

Comment: O.P. has an interesting point in light of this week's parsha. When the 1st communal commandment, sanctifying the New Moon was issued, Rash"i says that G-d showed Moses a drawing of the moon so that he could understand what it was about. Now, if that drawing had been part of the Torah, we probably would avoided several millenia of doubt and confusion. But, then again, Rav Gamliel & Sanhedrin might have not had much of a job to do. Prob. one reason for eliminating drawings is to have an Oral Law?

Comment: Not the Torah, but there are pictures in Joshua and Esther: "כל השירות כולן נכתבות אריח על גבי לבינה ולבינה על גבי אריח חוץ משירה זו ומלכי כנען שאריח על גבי אריח ולבינה על גבי לבינה מאי טעמא שלא תהא תקומה למפלתן" (_Bavli M'gila_ 16).